# Local maximum or minimum of a smooth function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function with positive definite Hassian at every . Let $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ be a critical point of $f$ then

$A.$ $f$ has global minimum at $(a,b).$

$B.$ $f$ has a local , but not global minimum at $(a,b).$

$C.$ $f$ has a local, but not global maximum at $(a,b).$

$D.$ $f$ has a global maximum at $(a,b).$

I only know that if Hassian matrix is positive definite definite at $(a,b)$ then it is a point of local minimum. Now what about global minimum? Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The answer should be $A$.

Comment: But sir how $A$ is answer....please give some explanation.....

Comment: My intuition tells me the function has to be convex (concave up).

Comment: Here's an example that comes to my mind: consider the function $f(x, y) = x^2+y^2$ then $\nabla^2 f = 2I$ at every point and $(0, 0)$ is a critical point.

Comment: But in our question at every point hassian matrix is positive definite...

Comment: In my example the hessian is positive definite everywhere since $\nabla^2 f = 2I$.

Comment: You example is suitable exactly but i want some general thinking...

Comment: According to yours example it is clear that answer is $A.$

Comment: @FaraadArmwood there is some example as discussed in our chat..

Comment: Ah, I see. I was being silly.

Comment: I think if Hassian matrix is positive definite everywhere then function will have at most one critical point???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Hessian is positive semi definite then $f$ is convex and any stationary point is a global minimum.

Comment: Yes as i thought in my last comment...but how?

Comment: It is not hard to show that a differentiable convex function satisfies $f(y)-f(x) \ge Df(x)(y-x)$. Hence if $Df(x) = 0$, we have $f(y) \ge f(x)$ for all $y$. (Is that what you were asking?)

Comment: Can i say that if Hessian matrix negative semi definite then $f$ is concave??

Comment: Yes, because $f$ is concave **iff** $-f$ is convex.

Comment: Ok sir thanks....

Comment: You are very welcome!